# Error: no implicit conversion of Symbol into Intege

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to ruby on rails and i want to create a session for each signed in user.
but I get that error.
In my controller I have :

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create
user =User.find_by pseudo :params[:pseudo]
if user
  session[:user_id]=user.id
  flash[:notice]= "you are signed in! "
  redirect root_url
else
  flash.now[:alert]= "wrong password/pseudo"
  render 'new'
end
end

def destroy
session[:user_id]=nil
flash[:notice]='You are now signed out'
redirect root_url
end
end
```

in my new.html.erb:

```
<h1>Sessions#new</h1>
<%= form_tag sessions_path do  %>
<div>
<%=label_tag 'pseudo', 'pseudo' %>
<%= text_field_tag 'pseudo' %>
</div>
<div>
  <%= label_tag 'password', 'password' %>
  <%= password_field_tag 'password' %>
</div>
  <%= submit_tag 'log in' %>


<% end %>
```

and in my index I have :

```
<h1>Users#index</h1>
<% if current_user.present? %>
Welcome <%= current_user.pseudo %> | <%= link_to 'Sign out' , logout_path %>

<% else %>
<%= link_to 'Register', new_user_url %><br/>
<%= link_to 'SignIn', login_path %>
<% end %>
```

in the application_controller.rb:

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  helper_method :current_user
  private
  def current_user
  User.find_by id: session[:user_id] if session[:user_id]
  end
  end
```

and that error is related to "user =User.find_by pseudo :params[:pseudo]" and i did not understand why

Comment: in ```create``` action: ```user = User.find_by pseudo: params[:pseudo]```

Comment: yes you are right thanks but i still have one more problem i got this error now "No route matches [GET] "/sessions" known that my routes are like this: Helper  HTTP Verb  Path  Controller#Action
Path / Url    
sessions_new_path  GET  /sessions/new(.:format)  sessions#new
root_path  GET  /  users#index
users_path  POST  /users(.:format)  users#create
new_user_path  GET  /users/new(.:format)  users#new
sessions_path  POST  /sessions(.:format)  sessions#create
login_path  GET  /login(.:format)  sessions#new
logout_path  GET  /logout(.:format)  sessions#destroy

Comment: add new method ```def index end``` to your SessionsController controller and read more about routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: thanks! and I am sorry for this stupid questions I will read more about routing !